# Illegal 'sec-websocket-protocol' header: Invalid input 'EOI', expected sec-websocket-protocol

Tags: websocket, akka-http

I'm trying to connect on Kubernetes websocket API but I get this error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Message failed with status code 400 Bad Request; Error info: ErrorInfo(Illegal 'sec-websocket-protocol' header: Invalid input 'EOI', expected sec-websocket-protocol (line 1, column 1),
^)
    at akka.http.impl.engine.ws.WebSocketClientBlueprint$UpgradeStage$1$$anon$1.onPush(WebSocketClientBlueprint.scala:107)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:747)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:649)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:471)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.receive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:410)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:603)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:618)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:502)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:500)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:529)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

I must be missing some configuration, do you knwo where this comes from?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got over it by defining `subprotocol` to `channel.k8s.io`:

```
WebSocketRequest(
  uri,
  extraHeaders = List(token),
  subprotocol = Option("channel.k8s.io")
)
```